# Browserify - exposing bundle internals

Tags: browserify

I want to know if it's possible to access the internals of one Browserify-generated bundle from another, assuming they're both already loaded on the same page. Here's an example:

If I have one bundle (bundle-a) consisting of:

```
index.js
menu.js
```

And a second bundle (bundle-b) consisting of just:

```
index.js (requires bundle-a/menu.js)
```

Then can I have my second bundle access the contents of the first bundle as indicated without bundling the two together. i.e.:

*bundle-b/index.js*

```
var Menu = require("bundle-a/menu.js");
```

Then how can I make this work assuming that both bundle-a and bundle-b have been loaded?

```
<script src="bundle-a.js"></script>
<script src="bundle-b.js"></script>
```

Is this at all possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since menu.js is required from both bundles, it should be compiled separately.

See https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles

So you could do:

```
$ browserify -r ./menu.js > static/menu.js
$ browserify -x ./menu.js bundle-a.js > static/bundle-a.js
$ browserify -x ./menu.js bundle-b.js > static/bundle-b.js
```